# “ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis” using insrt function with PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote this code using a portion of query in a string. Inside the string I'm using INSTR FUNCTION to split a multi value selection. Anyway, when I run this code I'm keeping  to get the error message:"“ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis”

```
sql_1 varchar2(4000);
sql_2 varchar2(4000);
year varchar2(100);

sql_1:='select count(*) ';  
year:='2019:2020'; 
sql_view_column:='v_cod_device';
type_selection:='03L20';


if selection= 'M' then
      sql_2:=sql_2||'MONTH '; 
      sql_2:=sql_2||'where  '||sql_view_column||' = '''||type_selection||''' and instr( '':'' '''||year||''' '':'' , '':'' v_year '':'' ) >0 ';
    end if;


 command_sql:=sql_1||sql_2;


  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command_sql 
  INTO counter;
```

When my code runs the execute immediate comand_sql statement, I will get the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
sql_1 := 'select count(*) ';
```

with

```
sql_1 := 'select count(*) FROM '; -- added FROM here
```

and

```
sql_2:=sql_2||'where  '||sql_view_column||' = '''||type_selection||''' and instr( '':'' '''||year||''' '':'' , '':'' v_year '':'' ) >0 ';
```

with

```
sql_2:=sql_2|| 'where  '|| sql_view_column ||' = '''|| type_selection ||''' and instr( '':'' || '''|| year ||''' || '':'' , '':'' || v_year || '':'' ) >0 ' ;
```

**Note:** in the above string, You have not used proper `single quotes` which are corrected in replace string. Also, Your code will not work if the condition `if selection= 'M' then` is false. You need to handle it correctly.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten in my thread this statement:```sql_1:='select count(*) '; ```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do ..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you put your code into an anonymous block, and change the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` into a `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to test it out, this is what you get:

```
select count(*) MONTH 
where  v_cod_device = '03L20' 
and instr( ':' '2019:2020' ':' , ':' v_year ':' ) >0
```

You can see there is no `FROM` and the `instr()` syntax is wrong. Here is the anonymous block that I used to troubleshoot this:

```
DECLARE
   sql_1             VARCHAR2 (4000);
   sql_2             VARCHAR2 (4000);
   year              VARCHAR2 (100);
   sql_view_column   VARCHAR2 (100);
   type_selection    VARCHAR2 (100);
   selection         VARCHAR2 (100)  :=  'M';
   command_sql       VARCHAR2 (8000);
   counter           NUMBER;
BEGIN
   sql_1 := 'select count(*) ';
   year := '2019:2020';
   sql_view_column := 'v_cod_device';
   type_selection := '03L20';

   IF selection = 'M' THEN
      sql_2 := sql_2 || 'MONTH ';
      sql_2 := sql_2 || 'where  ' || sql_view_column || ' = ''' || type_selection || ''' and instr( '':'' ''' || year || ''' '':'' , '':'' v_year '':'' ) >0 ';
   END IF;

   command_sql := sql_1 || sql_2;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (command_sql);
   --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command_sql INTO counter;

END;
```

Not having any idea what you want to accomplish, I might make a random guess that you are trying to do something like this?

```
IF selection = 'M' THEN
  sql_2 := sql_2 || 'from MONTH ';
  sql_2 := sql_2 || 'where  ' || sql_view_column || ' = ''' || type_selection || ''' ';

  IF instr(year, ':') > 0 THEN
     sql_2 := sql_2
      || ' and year between ' || substr(year, 0, instr(year, ':')-1) || ' and ' || substr(year, instr(year, ':')+1);
  ELSE
     sql_2 := sql_2
      || ' and year = ' || year;
  END IF;

END IF;
```

...which would result in:

```
select count(*) 
from MONTH 
where  v_cod_device = '03L20'  and year between 2019 and 2020
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot a statement. Anyway thaks a lot for your help